# How to use a variable from a custom php file in a htaccess file?

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, apache2.4

I use Apache 2.4 and PHP 7.4 in combination with WordPress.
On the server, I host videos in MP4 format, which should not be freely available on the Internet. So I modified the htaccess file to only allow certain websites to access and retrieve this content. The disadvantage is that the files are no longer downloadable and can no longer be streamed to a Chromecast. I would like to allow that in certain cases. I.e. I want to achieve that this is possible if you have the same IP-address as the server. The server is in my home network and I want all users of the home network to be able to access it freely. Everyone else doesn't.
This is what my Apache file current looks like:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
</IfModule>


<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /wp-content/uploads/ [NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https://tv.xn--dnte-0ra.de/ 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https://fileserver02.syn-nas.provided-by-versatel.duentetech.de/
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https://mediathek.xn--dnte-0ra.de/ 
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^92.117.246.86 //That was the server's (and network's) IP address a few days ago. As long as the IP address does not change, this type of access works. Due to the dynamic IP addresses, this address changes almost daily. Therefore, this should be entered automatically when the page is called up.
#RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^$server_ip;

RewriteRule .mp4 / [R=301]

</IfModule>

#Mediathek-Zugriff
# BEGIN WordPress
# Die Anweisungen (Zeilen) zwischen „BEGIN WordPress“ und „END WordPress“ sind
# dynamisch generiert und sollten nur über WordPress-Filter geändert werden.
# Alle Änderungen an den Anweisungen zwischen diesen Markierungen werden überschrieben.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Ass you can see, I used a Variable called "$server_ip". This Variable is build in a php file, which is in the same directory as the htacces file.

This is the php file:

```
<?php
$ip_address = file_get_contents('http://checkip.dyndns.org');


$ip_address = preg_replace('/[^0-9.]/', '', $ip_address);


$server_ip = $ip_address;


$file = fopen("ipneu.txt", "a");


fwrite($file, $server_ip . "\n");


fclose($file);

#putenv("IPADRESSE=$server_ip");
?>
```

Ultimately, I want to ensure that the IP address that the PHP file outputs is in the RewriteRule.

What do you thing about it?

Sorry for the possibly stupid questions, but unfortunately I'm not very familiar with apache server configurautoin.

Thanks a lot!

Greetings

Luca

I have several solutions, but I always get nowhere.

1. The IP address is transferred to the htaccess file in the variable
2. The IP address is written to a file in the same directory and from there passed on to the htaccess file.
   Ultimately, I want to ensure that the IP address that the PHP file outputs is in the RewriteRule.

Depending on what I tried, I got an http 500 failure, or it had no effect.
One of the things i tried is:
php_value auto_prepend_file /pfad/zur/datei.php

Comment: You are trying to insert a variable into a config file loaded to run the service that offers the file you want to use for getting the variable. This endangers the existence of the entire universe!

Answer (score 0):

You can't run a php file in a htaccess file. The htaccess is an apache configuration file which runs way before everything else.

You're relying on an external service right now (dyndns.org) which is not the best option. You don't do any checks if the API is working or not.

You can use `$_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR']` to determine the server's IP address with PHP.

You can check for HTTP_HOST in htaccess to retreive the server's host but you need to check if it's an IP address as well.

**Another suggestion:**

If you want to access if freely from you home network it's really easy:

Set up a domain (there are some free services for that) and set the A record for the servers local IP address (192.168.0.something). The name can be really meaningless as well, because only you know what that is.

Comment: $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'] does not exist when called from CLI

Comment: Hey, I see the problems you raise. I've chosen dyndns, since this is considered reliable. But an additional review of the answer seems quite reasonable.

I don't quite understand your suggestion yet, could you explain it in detail?
For the general setup:
The server is connected via Dynamic DNS and there is a corresponding rule in the firewall. However, the provider deactivates A Records as soon as I want to use Dynamic DNS. Logical. The domain itself is not a problem. I have a correspondingly large package, but I would still use a subdomain.

Comment: I suggest you to create a subdomain (videos.yourdomain.com) and set the A record of the subdomain to the local IP (192.168.0.X). This way when you open it from anywhere in the world it shows the content from the local host of everyone itself. So if I'm opening videos.yourdomain.com I'll see my server at home (If the local IP matches).